# Angular DomSanitizer adding extra tags to html sent as strings

Tags: html, angular, security, xss

I was trying to sanitize my values before displaying on anywhere UI like saved inputs, tables, etc.
when the value `<div><div>` is passed to the sanitize() function it returns `<div><div></div></div>`

return this.domSanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, value);

Answer (score 0):

That's one of the expected sanitization tasks from Angular DOMSanitizer.
It calls [endElement](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/470738c8f775145630a07be783e50dac5d2194e5/packages/core/src/sanitization/html_sanitizer.ts#L185)

```
private endElement(current: Element) {
    const tagName = current.nodeName.toLowerCase();
    if (VALID_ELEMENTS.hasOwnProperty(tagName) && !VOID_ELEMENTS.hasOwnProperty(tagName)) {
      this.buf.push('</');
      this.buf.push(tagName);
      this.buf.push('>');
    }
  }
```

During its `sanitizeChildren` [routine](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/470738c8f775145630a07be783e50dac5d2194e5/packages/core/src/sanitization/html_sanitizer.ts#L132-L136)